# Nitronate anion reduction with TiCl3. Nef reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

We can do the Nef reaction, by treatment of nitronate anion with $\ce{TiCl3}$. Here is the mechanism from article:

[image]

And I can’t understand what is exactly happening in $35\to38$ or $36\to37$. Can you please show precisely with arrows what is going on? Precise mechanism

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we go from 35 to 38 or from 36 to 37, the Ti(IV) species $\ce{TiOCl2}$ is leaving. Since the titanium entered as $\ce{Ti^{III}Cl3}$, this represents a net one-electron reduction.

But wait, there's more. The 36$\to$37 step requires adding another electron to neutralize the positive charge on 36, and if we treat the hydroxyl hydrogen on 38 as protic then that molecule also needs an additional electron. In either case a second $\ce{TiCl3}$ must be introduced at the 36$\to$37 or 35$\to$38 step as the source of this electron, so we have a two-electron reduction of the organic molecule using two $\ce{TiCl3}$ molecules in all. The charge on titanium from the second $\ce{TiCl3}$ molecule is balanced by accepting the chloride ion that the first $\ce{TiCl3}$ molecule surrendered to add to the oxygen earlier in the mechanism.

Below, I add the additional $\ce{TiCl3}$ molecule indicating where the electron from that molecule goes.

[image]

Thus we render the overall reaction:

$\ce{(CH3)2C^0H–N^{III}O2 +2Ti^{III}Cl3 -> (CH3)2C^{II}=O + Ti^{IV}OCl2 + Ti^{IV}Cl4 + N^{-I}H2OH}$

where oxidation states (based on expected bond polarities) on the atoms that are oxidized or reduced are indicated. Note that even though the substrate was reduced by two electrons, the nitrogen atom in the nitro group took four leaving the carbon in a higher oxidation state.